# Why does GitHub block some packages from installing but not others?

Tags: github, dependencies, aurelia, jspm

I went through the documentation on setting up an `Aurelia`[skeleton project](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/tree/master/skeleton-esnext) only to find that, while my simple page was loading, a lot of dependencies were missing. Therefore, the page wasn't loading in its entirety and looked rather ugly.

After some research about how downloading a lot off of GitHub can make the site suspicious, I found that once I ran

`jspm registry config GitHub`

and configured my GitHub account, I could run

`jspm install -y`

to find that *all* of the dependencies would now download. I was able to reproduce the issue and consistently solve it.

Why did GitHub block only *some* dependencies (like `font-awesome`) and not others?

Comment: Failing silently sure is fun :-/